# Debian: ¿por qué localhost no muestra el index de apache?

Tags: wordpress, apache, debian, localhost

Instalé wordpress local e intenté habilitar el certificado de seguridad al protocolo http utilizando openssl, algo debí de haber configurado muy mal porque ahora que me arrepentí (ya que ni funcionó), al escribir `localhost` en la barra de direcciones del navegador me continúa apareciendo el nombre de dominio que escribí en el archivo `000-default.conf` para redireciones: `Redirect permanent "/" "https://tienda-josting/"`.

fueron tantos comandos los que metí que me guiaré de la pila en el historial del bash, tal vez puedan ayudarme a quitar eso.

```
# openssl genrsa -out /etc/ssl/private/rootCA.key 2048 -des3
# openssl req -new -x509 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/rootCA.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem -days 365
# touch /etc/ssl/index.txt
# echo '01' >> /etc/ssl/serial
# openssl genrsa -out /etc/ssl/private/dispositivo.key 2048
# openssl req -new -key /etc/ssl/private/dispositivo.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/dispositivo.csr
# openssl x509 -req -in /etc/ssl/certs/dispositivo.csr -CA /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem -CAkey /etc/ssl/private/rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out /etc/ssl/certs/device.crt -days 365
# a2enmod ssl
# a2enmod headers
# a2ensite default-ssl.conf
# systemctl restart apache2
```

todos esos o la mayoría, sacados de un tutorial en YT. también probé los siguientes antes, sacados de una página web pero no me había dado el problema que les menciono e igualmente no funcionó la configuración del certificado:

```
$ sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/ssl-params.conf
```

todo esto dentro de ssl-params.conf:

```
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
# Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
# the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
# Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
# Requires Apache >= 2.4
SSLCompression off
SSLUseStapling on
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"
# Requires Apache >= 2.4.11
SSLSessionTickets Off
```

```
$ sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf.bak
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

dentro de default-ssl.conf:

```
ServerName tienda-josting

SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
```

```
$ sudo a2enmod ssl
$ sudo a2enmod headers
$ sudo a2ensite default-ssl
$ sudo a2enconf ssl-params
$ sudo apache2ctl configtest
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

fue todo lo que hice, la 2da guía de comandos sólo me facilitó navegar a mi sitio local con un nombre **tienda-josting**. pero con la primera guía de comandos (en modo root #) (que ingresé ya de último para intentar lo del certificado) ahora no me muestra el sitio local, me aparece **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN** en el navegador, ni el index de apache muestra si ingreso `localhost`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si accedo así: `127.0.0.1/algo` aparece el código .php impreso en el navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya purgue apache como 3 veces, reinstalé, inicié, detuve, recargué, eliminé caché dns y nada.
ayudaaaa! porfavor.

**ACTUALIZACION**

agregué la siguiente fila, sin borrar nada, al archivo `hosts` ubicado en mi caso en `/etc/hosts`:
`127.0.0.1    tienda-josting`
de ese modo, al ingresar `locahost` en la barra de navegación, **si** me muestra el index de apache y así: `localhost/tienda-josting` me manda a mi proyecto.

Comment: Recuperando de los respaldos `000-default.conf.bak` y `default-ssl.conf.bak` debería ser suficiente. ¿Modificaste/creaste algún otro .conf?

Comment: sobreescribi la copia ```000-default.conf.bak``` ya que no conforme con que no haya funcionado a la primera, puse los comandos nuevamente y se me fue el ```sudo cp /etc/apache2/...``` pero cuando lo purgué (apache) fui a verificar si ```000-default.conf``` y ```default-ssl.conf``` se habían eliminado y así fue, al instalarlo de nuevo allí aparecieron sin modificaciones pero el virtualhost **tienda-josting* como que se quedó bloqueado.

Comment: ¿En tu servidor DNS local has configurado la resolución DNS de `tienda-josting`? ¿Has editado el archivo `hosts` local de tu máquina en su lugar? El error `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` es debido a que tu navegador no es capaz de resolver a una IP el nombre de dominio indicado.

Comment: no configuré nada en el servidor dns local pues cuando apliqué la configuración por primera vez si me funcionaba, tecleaba ```localhost/wordpress``` y me mandaba al index. tampoco toqué el archivo ```host``` pero si lo vi, tiene 2 columnas: ```127.0.0.1 localhost``` más abajo algo relacionado con ipv6. investigaré respecto a la configuración del servidor dns.

Comment: php si, la versión 7.4.21 tengo pero ese paquete ```libapache2-mod-php``` lo instalé recién porque parece que no lo tenía.

Comment: Me parece muy bien que te funcionara antes, ahora no. Revísalo, para que te funcione ese nombre DNS deberás ponerlo a la derecha de `localhost`. Otro tema:  ¿Instalaste PHP? `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php...`.

Comment: así también lo he probado: ```localhost/tienda-josting```, en ese caso me dice que no existe. error 404. estoy investigando respecto al servidor dns.

Comment: No es necesario un servidor DNS, te podría valer modificar el archivo `hosts` como te dije. En cuanto a la URL, no puedes cambiar el directorio sin renombrarlo en la máquina con `mv`. ¿Para qué necesitas la redirección si no sabes configurar resolución DNS local personalizada? Parece que tu principal problema es que no tienes PHP instalado o activado. Quitando la redirección o haciéndola correctamente a `localhost` solucionarías el problema de la redirección a una DNS que no existe.

Comment: tengo php, la versión 7.4 pero no sé de qué configuraciones me hablas, mencionas un archivo que nunca toqué ```host``` nunca lo toqué.

Comment: Para no alargar la conversación a base de comentarios, [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129102/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-lorelei-symphony).